# .stopPropagation() is TOO thorough :/

Tags: jquery, click, lightbox, colorbox

I have some code. Basically the entire DIV is clickable, but I need ONE button within that DIV to perform a different function to the rest of the DIV, I've tried `.stopPropagation()` but it's TOO thorough, as it disables the OTHER function I am trying to run on `.CLICK()`.

The button in question (is next to "+ add item") and has unfortunately collapsed, but it still clickable. You'll see that it is supposed to fire a lightbox, but it also adds the product to the DIV above it. I want to fire JUST the lightbox, but NOT add the product into my "basket", can anyone steer me in the right direction? My code is below;

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" id="partnumbers" name="partnumbers" action="formHandler">
<div id="specialOffer">
<ul>
    <li>
    <div id="prodD">
        <input type="hidden" name="partNum_1" id="catnum1" value="" />
        <div id="close" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Remove X</a></div>
        <div id="Prod1"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id="prodO">
        <input type="hidden" name="partNum_2" id="catnum2" value="" />
        <div id="close" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Remove X</a></div>
        <div id="Prod2"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id="prodA">
        <input type="hidden" name="partNum_3" id="catnum3" value="" />
        <div id="close" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Remove X</a></div>
        <div id="Prod3"></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div id="prodSubmit">
        <input name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="flyout1">
<ul class="paginate-1">
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9059863">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9087361">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9087378">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9087354">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
    <li><div id="subProd" class="9059791">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/placeholder.jpg" width="110" height="110" />
    <span class="product">
    <p class="title">PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <p class="number">PARTnum</p>
        <p class="price">Price</p>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="button">+ Add item</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="qv"><img src="images/qv.png" width="17" height="17" /></a>
</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#specialOffer, #flyout1, #flyout2, #flyout3 {margin:0; padding:0; width:990px; overflow:hidden;}
#specialOffer {padding:10px 0 0 20px;}
#flyout1 {background:transparent url(../images/popupBG0.png) top left no-repeat;}

#specialOffer UL, UL.paginate-1, UL.paginate-2, UL.paginate-3 {
    float:left;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    height:260px;
    display:block;
}
#specialOffer UL {width:970px;}
#specialOffer UL, UL.paginate-3 {
    height:270px;
}
#specialOffer UL LI, UL.paginate-1 LI, UL.paginate-2 LI, UL.paginate-3 LI {
    float:left;
    margin:30px 30px 0 27px; padding:0;
    display:inline;
    width:130px;
    height:200px;
}
#specialOffer UL LI {
    height:220px;
}

#scrollable {
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:990px;
    border-top: 1px;
    border-top-color: #CCC;
    border-top-style: solid;
}

.pager {
  margin-right:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:1em 0;
  float:right;
}

.pager li{
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-right:.3em;
  font-size:1.1em;
}

.pager a{
  color:#FF9182;
  outline:none;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
.pager a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.pager .active a {
 color:#666;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.pager .disabled {
 width:32px;
 text-indent:-9999px;
}

/* Needed for carousel*/
.flexiwrap {
  margin:0 0 0 20px; padding:0;
  float:left;
  width:970px;
  height:271px;
}

/* PAGINATED CONTENT */
#Prod1, #Prod2, #Prod3, #subProd {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; width:130px;}
#Prod4 {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; width:130px;}
#Prod1 img.thumb, #Prod2 img.thumb,
#Prod3 img.thumb, #subProd img.thumb {
    margin:0; padding:0 10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.button, .qv {
    float:left;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #eeeeee);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #666;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    overflow: visible;
}
.qv {
    z-index:9999px;
}
#Prod1 .qv, #Prod2 .qv,
#Prod3 .qv, #subProd .qv {
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:5px 5px 0px 6px;
}
#Prod1 .qv IMG, #Prod2 .qv IMG,
#Prod3 .qv IMG, #subProd .qv IMG {
    border:0 none;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

#Prod1 .product P, #Prod2 .product P,
#Prod3 .product P, #subProd .product P {margin:5px 0; padding:0; line-height:13px;}
#Prod1 .product .title, #Prod2 .product .title,
#Prod3 .product .title, #subProd .product .title {color:#666; font-size:13px;}
#Prod1 .product .number, #Prod2 .product .number,
#Prod3 .product .number, #subProd .product .number {color:#666; font-size:11px;}
#Prod1 .product .price, #Prod2 .product .price,
#Prod3 .product .price, #subProd .product .price {
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    line-height:20px;
}

#close {margin-top:-15px;}
#close a {float:right; margin:0; padding:0; text-decoration:none;}

#Prod1, #Prod2, #Prod3 {border:1px solid #ccc; height:110px; cursor:pointer;}
#prodDoll INPUT, #prodOutfit INPUT, #prodAcc INPUT {display:none;}
#Prod4 {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; width:130px; height:110px; cursor:pointer;}
#subProd {cursor: pointer;}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#flyout1').hide();
$('#prodSubmit').hide();

$('#flyout1 #subProd').click(function() {
    var id1 = $(this).attr('class');
    $("#catnum1").val(id1);  
    $("#Prod1").html($("." + $(this).attr('class')).html());
    $("#Prod1").css("border", "none");
    $("#prodD #close").css("display", "block");
    $("#prodD .button, #prodD .qv").css("display", "none");
    $("#Prod1").attr('rel', 'done');
});

$("#prodD #close a").click(function() {
    $("#prodD #close").css("display", "none");
    $("#Prod1").empty();
    $("#Prod1").css("border", "1px solid #CCC");
    $("#Prod1").removeAttr("rel")
});

$("#Prod1").on("click",function(){
    $("#flyout1").slideToggle();
});

$("a.qv").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
$("a.qv").colorbox();
```

[and I have set up a fiddle here :)](http://jsfiddle.net/takuhii/T8d4t/4/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am probably missing the obvious :/

Comment: Its hard to see what you are looking for, you should just post a simple case which reproduce your issue.

Comment: The HTML suggests that `stopPropagation()` shouldn't be required. All clickable elements should be selectable independently for the purpose of attaching event handlers, without needing to worry about bubbling.

Comment: @ashish I did try that originally, but it makes no difference, it still adds the product to the empty DIV above it AND fires the lightbox :/

Comment: @roasted The JSFiddle replicates the problem (just take the .stopPropagation() away

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: There-in lies the problem really. The whole DIV needs to be selectable because it duplicates itself into one of the empty fields above, the 'a.qv' works, but works too well, so I need a way to switch the duplication off, but still enable my lightbox :/

Comment: Don't attach the click handler directly to the `subProd` wrapper in the template. Delegate it upwards so that subProd can be cloned without the handler.  Also, duplicate ids can't help. Ids must be unique. Try reversing the use of class and id in the wrapper divs to give `<div class="subProd" id="9059863">`.

Comment: I have to confess to not really being able to penetrate what is supposed to happen so find it hard to debug.

Comment: I tried attached the click handler to elements within the subProd DIV, but it just F's things up by either adding individual elements to the empty DIVs, or by adding the same DIV regardless of where I click.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Try taking away the .stopPropagation() from the JSFiddle I made, then hit the link, you'll see that it adds content to the empty DIV and fires the lightbox. I just want the lightbox to fire and nothing else :/

http://jsfiddle.net/takuhii/T8d4t/5/

Comment: takuhii, I don't understand the fiddle any more than the code.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot It's the code exactly as i am using it, I'm not sure how else I can elaborate :/ It's the button labelled QV, you'll see that it adds information to a DIV AND fires a lightbox, I just need a way to stop it adding information to the lightbox, but still fire the lightbox :/ **Updated:** http://jsfiddle.net/takuhii/T8d4t/8/

Comment: takuhii, sorry,I have been less than 10% committed to looking at your problem and have been unfairly critical. I must disappear to work now but will look in again later today.

Comment: That should read less than "100% committed". Anyway, I have now added an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, you are effectively snookered since colorbox seems to rely on event bubbling, so `e.preventDefault()` blocks its action. Straightforwardly, you can have either colorbox or prevent the click event bubbling, but not both.

A stackoverflow search reveals that others have suffered the same problem though I can't find a scenario that precisely matches yours.

I tried various things and came up with the following approach (aka "hack") :

- create an invisible dummy link for the purpose of opening the colorbox
- append the dummy link directly to the document body so it not inside a problematic "subProd" div
- attach an event handler to the "qv" links which does `e.preventDefault()`, `e.stopPropagation()` then transfers its `href` to the dummy link before triggering a click on it.

The code is surprisingly simple :

```
var $dummyLink = $("<a/>").colorbox().appendTo("body").hide();

$("a.qv").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $dummyLink.attr('href', this.href).trigger('click');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9LfUB/8/)**

This seems to overcome the immediate issue.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there may be further work getting the colorbox to relate to the particular "qv" that was clicked. If that's an issue, then it's maybe better handled as a separate question.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! I've been looking at this problem for days, and it just gets to the point where you can't see the wood for the trees. I am the only person where I work that can do this, and I have rely on communities like StackOverflow for help, as there is no one else to help me :/

Comment: Got rid of $dummyLink and went for `url = $(this).attr('href'); window.open( url );`

Comment: @Duncanmoo, if that works then it's cool though I can't immediately see how you get the `.colorbox()` effect given to `$dummyLink`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of approaching this is along these lines:

```
$('.parent').once().on('click', function(e){
  // Don't apply if child link was clicked on.
  if (!$(e.target).is('.child')) {
    // Background click action
  }
});


$('.child').on('click', function(){
  // Child click action i.e. colorbox action
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Beetroot-Beetroot really helped me out here, but I've had to drop the use of colorbox, so just to share with everyone, I have altered the code to this;

```
var $dummyLink = $("a.qv").attr("href");
$("a.qv").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $dummyLink.attr('href', this.href).trigger('click');
});
```

It works perfectly for me, I hope it can go towards helping someone in a similar situation.